# how to insert value into a databse using dropdown in php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to add values to my database using this code, but it doesn't work.

#### index.html

```
    <html>
<head>
<body>
<select style="width:200px;" name="eventList" tabindex="5">
//Three option values in a group

<form action="reg.php" method=POST>

<input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

#### php file

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('reg');
$list = isset($_POST['eventList']) ? $_POST['eventList'] : '';
$query = "INSERT INTO 'reg1' ('choice') VALUES ('$list')";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
                            
    if ($result) {
    // Success!
        echo " Success ";                           
        } else {
                    // Display error message.
        echo "<p>Updation Failed</p>";
                   echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";                         
              }                         
                        
?>
```

When I click on the submit button, I get an error:

```
Updation Failed

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL   server version for the right syntax to use near ''reg1' ('choice') VALUES ('Vogue')' at line 1
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Every php code line should end with `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('reg');
    $list = isset($_POST['eventList']) ? $_POST['eventList'] : '';
    $query = "INSERT INTO `reg1` (`choice`) VALUES ('$list')";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
         if ($result) {
            // Success!
            echo " Success ";                           
          } else {
            // Display error message.
            echo "<p>Updation Failed</p>";
            echo "<p>" . mysql_error() . "</p>";                            
                            }                           

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget `;`:

```
mysql_select_db(reg);
```

And use single quotes:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `reg1` (`choice`) VALUES ('$list')";
```

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant reg - assumed 'reg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\reg.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: eventList in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\reg.php on line 4
Updation Failed

Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Got this error

Comment: `mysql_select_db('reg')` - reg isn't constant, it's a string!

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: eventList in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\reg.php on line 4
Updation Failed

Unknown column '' in 'field list'

And now this

Comment: `$list = isset($_POST['eventList']) ? $_POST['eventList'] : '';`

Comment: Updation Failed

Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Comment: "INSERT INTO `reg1` (`choice`) VALUES ('$list')"; - Use single quotes in `($list)`

Comment: It's already in single quotes

Comment: no, it's a ` symbol!!! You need to use ' !

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `reg1` (`choice`) VALUES (`.$list`)";
```

**Should be:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `reg1` (`choice`) VALUES ('$list')";
```

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant reg - assumed 'reg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\reg.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: eventList in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\reg.php on line 4
Updation Failed

Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Got this error

Comment: Ok, update your post with the HTML from `<select>` and not just part of it, did you close it with `</select>`?

Comment: <select style="width:200px;" name="eventList" tabindex="5">

         <option value="select">Select Event</option>

         <optgroup label="Specials">

           <option value="Vogue">Vogue</option>

           <option value="Raddrock">Raddrock</option>

           <option value="Razzmatazz">Razzmatazz</option>

         </optgroup>
         </select>
        
        <form action="reg.php" method=POST>
         <input type="submit" value="register">

        </form>

Comment: The `<select>` should be inside your `<form>`

Comment: Updation Failed

Unknown column 'Vogue' in 'field list'

I get this after doing it

Comment: Please update your question with all the new code. Do not comment here, update your question.